# php - how to check multidemisonal array 's values are all zero?

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have an array as following,

```
$array = array(
  'foo1' => 
    array (
      'a' =>  0,
      'b' =>  0, ),
  'bar'=> 
    array (
      'a' =>  0,
      'c' =>  1, ),
);
```

How can I check if the values in array are all 0 or not? Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output? What you have tried so far? Post your attempts too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to check the whole array, you could just map out the elements then using `array_sum`. Then just use a simple `if`:

```
$check = array_sum(array_map(function($e){
    return array_sum($e);
}, $array));

if($check > 0) {
    // do what you have to do
}
```

Although this is accepted, without taking into account array indices, you could compare another multi-dimensional with `[0, 0]` with each batch with `array_filter`. Then, if both count matches, its all zero:

```
$check = array_filter($array, function($v){
    $count = count($v);
    return array_fill(0, $count, 0) === array_values($v);
});

if(count($check) !== count($array)) {
    // not all zero
}
```

Or another way with SPL:

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
$found_non_zero = false;
foreach($it as $val) {
    if($val !== 0) {
        $found_non_zero = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($found_non_zero) {
    // do something
}
```

Or `array_walk_recursive` as @splash suggested:

```
$found_non_zero = false;
array_walk_recursive($array, function($e){
    if($e !== 1) {
        $found_non_zero = true;
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Good one so far (Y)

Comment: test this arrray - `[1,-1]`

Comment: it works..sorry I forgot to mention that the values will be all unsigned integer.

Comment: @Ghost I would use array_walk_recursive to find non-zero

Comment: @splash58 or SPL Iterator with a simple true false flag

Comment: @Ghost It's maybe even better

Answer (score 0):

If it is a 2D array, you can iterate over all the values and use a Boolean to check if all the values are zero or not.

```
$check=0;  
foreach($array as $firstArray){
  foreach($firstArrayas as $value){
    if($value!=0){
     $check = 1;
    }
  } 
 } 

if($check===1){
 echo "One of the values is not zero";
}
else{
  echo "All values are zero";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array(
 'foo1' => 
   array (
    'a' =>  0,
    'b' =>  0, ),
'bar'=> 
  array (
    'a' =>  0,
    'c' =>  1, ),
);

$sum = 0;
foreach ($array as $inner):
    $sum = $sum + array_sum($inner);
    if($sum > 0):
        break; // if already greater than zero , no need to continue looping
    endif;
endforeach;

echo ($sum >0)?"Not All Zero":"All Zero";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**`array_filter()`**](http://www.php.net/array_filter) to get an array of all items that are non-zero. After that, use [**`empty()`**](http://www.php.net/empty) on that resulting array, to determine if it's empty.

For example, with your example array :

```
$array = array(
  'foo1' => 
    array (
      'a' =>  0,
      'b' =>  0, ),
  'bar'=> 
    array (
      'a' =>  0,
      'c' =>  1, ),
);
```

Using the following portion of code :

```
$data = array_filter($array);

if (empty($data)) {
    echo "Zeros";
} else {
    echo "No zeros";
}
```

Would get you the output "Zeros" or "No zeros".

Answer (score 0):

One way is this

```
<?php
$test = ["a"=>[0,0], "b"=>[0,1]];
foreach($test as $key=>$value){
  if (array_sum($value)==0) {
       echo "$key as all zeros\n";
  }
}
?>
```

check here : https://eval.in/608382